# MERN, Apollo Sandbox, MongoDB mutations adding subdocs using input types in typeDefs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, graphql, mutation

The following questions are for a Node server application in javascript running express, apollo-server-express, mongoose and graphql.

This is the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "dimond-media-mern-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {     
    "dev": "concurrently \"cd server && npm run start\" \"cd client && npm start\"",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "watch": "nodemon",
    "seed": "node seeders/seed.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@graphql-tools/load-files": "^6.6.1",
    "@graphql-tools/merge": "^8.3.12",
    "@graphql-tools/schema": "^9.0.10",
    "apollo-server-express": "^3.6.1",
    "concurrently": "^7.6.0",
    "express": "^4.17.2",
    "graphql": "^16.2.0",
    "mongoose": "^6.1.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.3"
  }
}
```

################################################################

This is the server.js file:

```
const express = require("express");
const { ApolloServer } = require("apollo-server-express");
const path = require("path");

const { typeDefs, resolvers } = require("./schemas");
const db = require("./config/connection");

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
const app = express();
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
});

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../client/build/index.html"));
});

// Create a new instance of an Apollo server with the GraphQL schema
const startApolloServer = async (typeDefs, resolvers) => {
  await server.start();
  server.applyMiddleware({ app });

  db.once("open", () => {
    app.listen(PORT, () => {
      console.log(`API server running on port ${PORT}!`);
      console.log(
        `Use GraphQL at http://localhost:${PORT}${server.graphqlPath}`
      );
    });
  });
};

// Call the async function to start the server
startApolloServer(typeDefs, resolvers);
```

################################################################

This is the Quote model (Quote.js):

```
const { Schema, model } = require("mongoose");
const dateFormat = require("../utils/dateFormat");

const quoteSchema = new Schema({
  quoteDate: { type: String, minlength: 1, maxlength: 280, trim: true },
  startDate: { type: String, minlength: 1, maxlength: 280, trim: true },
  endDate: { type: String, minlength: 1, maxlength: 280, trim: true },
  cameras: [
    {
      name: {
        type: String,
      },
      manufacturer: { type: String },
      description: { type: String },
      accessories: { type: String },
      quantity: { type: String },
      value: { type: String },
    },
  ],
  audios: [
    {
      name: {
        type: String,
      },
      manufacturer: { type: String },
      description: { type: String },
      accessories: { type: String },
      quantity: { type: String },
      value: { type: String },
    },
  ],
  lightings: [
    {
      name: {
        type: String,
      },
      manufacturer: { type: String },
      description: { type: String },
      accessories: { type: String },
      quantity: { type: String },
      value: { type: String },
    },
  ],
  grips: [
    {
      name: {
        type: String,
      },
      manufacturer: { type: String },
      description: { type: String },
      accessories: { type: String },
      quantity: { type: String },
      value: { type: String },
    },
  ],
});

const Quote = model("Quote", quoteSchema);

module.exports = Quote;
```

################################################################

This is the Camera model (Camera.js):

```
const { Schema, model } = require("mongoose");
const dateFormat = require("../utils/dateFormat");

const camerasSchema = new Schema({
  bodies: [
    {
      name: {
        type: String,
        // required: "Please provide a name!",
        // minlength: 1,
        // maxlength: 280,
        trim: true,
      },
      manufacturer: { type: String, minlength: 1, maxlength: 280, trim: true },
      description: {
        type: String,
        // required: "Please provide a description!",
        // minlength: 1,
        // maxlength: 280,
        trim: true,
      },
      accessories: [
        {
          name: {
            type: String,
            // required: "Please provide a product name!",
            // minlength: 1,
            // maxlength: 280,
            trim: true,
          },
          description: {
            type: String,
            // required: "Please provide a description!",
            // minlength: 1,
            // maxlength: 280,
            trim: true,
          },
          quantity: {
            type: String,
          },
        },
      ],
      category: { type: String, trim: true },
      location: { type: String, minlength: 1, maxlength: 280, trim: true },
      purchased: String,
      quantity: String,
      value: String,
    },
  ],
  lenses: [
    {
      name: {
        type: String,
        // required: "Please provide a name!",
        // minlength: 1,
        // maxlength: 280,
        trim: true,
      },
      manufacturer: { type: String, minlength: 1, maxlength: 280, trim: true },
      description: {
        type: String,
        // required: "Please provide a description!",
        // minlength: 1,
        // maxlength: 280,
        trim: true,
      },
      accessories: [
        {
          name: {
            type: String,
            // required: "Please provide a product name!",
            // minlength: 1,
            // maxlength: 280,
            trim: true,
          },
          description: {
            type: String,
            // required: "Please provide a description!",
            // minlength: 1,
            // maxlength: 280,
            trim: true,
          },
          quantity: {
            type: String,
          },
        },
      ],
      category: { type: String, trim: true },
      location: { type: String, minlength: 1, maxlength: 280, trim: true },
      purchased: String,
      quantity: String,
      value: String,
    },
  ],
  flash: [
    {
      name: {
        type: String,
        // required: "Please provide a name!",
        // minlength: 1,
        // maxlength: 280,
        trim: true,
      },
      manufacturer: { type: String, minlength: 1, maxlength: 280, trim: true },
      description: {
        type: String,
        // required: "Please provide a description!",
        // minlength: 1,
        // maxlength: 280,
        trim: true,
      },
      accessories: [
        {
          name: {
            type: String,
            // required: "Please provide a product name!",
            // minlength: 1,
            // maxlength: 280,
            trim: true,
          },
          description: {
            type: String,
            // required: "Please provide a description!",
            // minlength: 1,
            // maxlength: 280,
            trim: true,
          },
          quantity: {
            type: String,
          },
        },
      ],
      category: { type: String, trim: true },
      location: { type: String, minlength: 1, maxlength: 280, trim: true },
      purchased: String,
      quantity: String,
      value: String,
    },
  ],
  monitors: [
    {
      name: {
        type: String,
        // required: "Please provide a name!",
        // minlength: 1,
        // maxlength: 280,
        trim: true,
      },
      manufacturer: { type: String, minlength: 1, maxlength: 280, trim: true },
      description: {
        type: String,
        // required: "Please provide a description!",
        // minlength: 1,
        // maxlength: 280,
        trim: true,
      },
      accessories: [
        {
          name: {
            type: String,
            // required: "Please provide a product name!",
            // minlength: 1,
            // maxlength: 280,
            trim: true,
          },
          description: {
            type: String,
            // required: "Please provide a description!",
            // minlength: 1,
            // maxlength: 280,
            trim: true,
          },
          quantity: {
            type: String,
          },
        },
      ],
      category: { type: String, trim: true },
      location: { type: String, minlength: 1, maxlength: 280, trim: true },
      purchased: String,
      quantity: String,
      value: String,
    },
  ],
  timecode: [
    {
      name: {
        type: String,
        // required: "Please provide a name!",
        // minlength: 1,
        // maxlength: 280,
        trim: true,
      },
      manufacturer: { type: String, minlength: 1, maxlength: 280, trim: true },
      description: {
        type: String,
        // required: "Please provide a description!",
        // minlength: 1,
        // maxlength: 280,
        trim: true,
      },
      accessories: [
        {
          name: {
            type: String,
            // required: "Please provide a product name!",
            // minlength: 1,
            // maxlength: 280,
            trim: true,
          },
          description: {
            type: String,
            // required: "Please provide a description!",
            // minlength: 1,
            // maxlength: 280,
            trim: true,
          },
          quantity: {
            type: String,
          },
        },
      ],
      category: { type: String, trim: true },
      location: { type: String, minlength: 1, maxlength: 280, trim: true },
      purchased: String,
      quantity: String,
      value: String,
    },
  ],
  cameraSupports: [
    {
      name: {
        type: String,
        // required: "Please provide a name!",
        // minlength: 1,
        // maxlength: 280,
        trim: true,
      },
      manufacturer: { type: String, minlength: 1, maxlength: 280, trim: true },
      description: {
        type: String,
        // required: "Please provide a description!",
        // minlength: 1,
        // maxlength: 280,
        trim: true,
      },
      accessories: [
        {
          name: {
            type: String,
            // required: "Please provide a product name!",
            // minlength: 1,
            // maxlength: 280,
            trim: true,
          },
          description: {
            type: String,
            // required: "Please provide a description!",
            // minlength: 1,
            // maxlength: 280,
            trim: true,
          },
          quantity: {
            type: String,
          },
        },
      ],
      category: { type: String, trim: true },
      location: { type: String, minlength: 1, maxlength: 280, trim: true },
      purchased: String,
      quantity: String,
      value: String,
    },
  ],
});

const Cameras = model("Cameras", camerasSchema);

module.exports = Cameras;
```

################################################################

This is the typeDefs.js file:

```
const { gql } = require("apollo-server-express");

const typeDefs = gql`
  type Cameras {
    _id: ID
    bodies: [Bodies]
    lenses: [Item]
    flash: [Item]
    monitors: [Item]
    timecode: [Item]
    cameraSupports: [Item]
  }

  type Bodies {
    _id: ID
    name: String
    manufacturer: String
    description: String
    accessories: [Accessories]
    category: String
    location: String
    purchased: String
    quantity: String
    value: String
  }

  type Audios {
    _id: ID
    mics: [Item]
    recorders: [Item]
    mixers: [Item]
    supports: [Item]
    cables: [Cables]
  }

  type Lightings {
    _id: ID
    lights: [Item]
    lightModifiers: [Item]
    lightSupports: [Item]
  }

  type Grips {
    _id: ID
    power: [Item]
    rigging: [Item]
    comms: [Item]
  }

  type Item {
    _id: ID
    name: String
    manufacturer: String
    description: String
    accessories: [Accessories]
    category: String
    location: String
    purchased: String
    quantity: String
    value: String
  }

  type Cables {
    _id: ID
    name: String
    manufacturer: String
    description: String
    category: String
    location: String
    purchased: String
    quantity: String
    value: String
  }

  type Accessories {
    _id: ID
    name: String
    description: String
    quantity: String
  }

  type Quote {
    _id: ID
    quoteDate: String
    startDate: String
    endDate: String
    cameras: [Cameras]
    audios: [Audios]
    lightings: [Lightings]
    grips: [Grips]
  }

  type Query {
    cameras: [Cameras]!
    audios: [Audios]!
    lightings: [Lightings]!
    grips: [Grips]!
    quote: [Quote]!
  }

  input AccessoriesInput {
    _id: ID
    name: String
    description: String
    quantity: String
  }

  input ItemInput {
    _id: ID
    name: String
    manufacturer: String
    description: String
    accessories: AccessoriesInput
    category: String
    location: String
    purchased: String
    quantity: String
    value: String
  }

  input BodiesInput {
    _id: ID
    name: String
    manufacturer: String
    description: String
    accessories: AccessoriesInput
    category: String
    location: String
    purchased: String
    quantity: String
    value: String
  }

  input CameraInput {
    _id: ID
    bodies: BodiesInput
    lenses: ItemInput
    flash: ItemInput
    monitors: ItemInput
    timecode: ItemInput
    cameraSupports: ItemInput
  }

  type Mutation {
    addQuote(
      quoteDate: String!
      startDate: String!
      endDate: String!
      cameras: [CameraInput]
    ): Quote
  }
`;

module.exports = typeDefs;
```

################################################################

This is the resolvers.js file:

```
const {
  Audios,
  Cameras,
  Lightings,
  Grips,
  Quote,
} = require("../models");

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    audios: async () => {
      return Audios.find();
    },
    cameras: async () => {
      return Cameras.find();
    },
    lightings: async () => {
      return Lightings.find();
    },
    grips: async () => {
      return Grips.find();
    },
    quote: async () => {
      return Quote.find();
    },
  },

  Mutation: {
    addQuote: async (parent, { quoteDate, startDate, endDate, cameras }) => {
      return Quote.create({
        quoteDate,
        startDate,
        endDate,
        cameras,
      });
    },
  },
};

module.exports = resolvers;
```

####################################################

This is the shape of the cameras object inside the addQuote mutation:

```
[
  {
    bodies: { name: 'r5c', manufacturer: 'Canon' },
    lenses: { name: 'D200', manufacturer: 'Nikon' },
    flash: { name: 'C100mkII', manufacturer: 'Canon' },
    monitors: { name: 'PD150', manufacturer: 'Sony' },
    timecode: { name: 'trv17', manufacturer: 'Sony' },
    cameraSupports: { name: '5DmkIII', manufacturer: 'Canon' }
  }
]
```

####################################################

This is the mutation operation I run in the apollo sandbox:

```
mutation Mutation($quoteDate: String!, $startDate: String!, $endDate: String!, $cameras: [CameraInput]) {
  addQuote(quoteDate: $quoteDate, startDate: $startDate, endDate: $endDate, cameras: $cameras) {
    quoteDate
    startDate
    endDate
    cameras {
      bodies {
        name
        manufacturer
      }
      cameraSupports {
        name
        manufacturer
      }
      flash {        
        name
        manufacturer
      }
      lenses {
        name
        manufacturer
      }
      monitors {
        name
        manufacturer
      }
      timecode {
        name
        manufacturer
      }
    }
  }
}
```

These are the variables:

```
{  "quoteDate": "now-12:58",
  "startDate": "later",
  "endDate": "whenever",
  "cameras":{
    "bodies":{
      "name":"r5c",
      "manufacturer": "Canon"
    },
    "cameraSupports":{
      "name":"5DmkIII",
      "manufacturer":"Canon"
      },
    "flash":{
      "name":"C100mkII",
      "manufacturer":"Canon"
      },
    "lenses":{
      "name":"D200",
      "manufacturer":"Nikon"
      },
    "monitors":{
      "name":"PD150",
      "manufacturer":"Sony"
      },
    "timecode":{
      "name":"trv17",
      "manufacturer":"Sony"
      }
  }
}
```

####################################################

This is the response:

```
{
  "data": {
    "addQuote": {
      "quoteDate": "now-12:58",
      "startDate": "later",
      "endDate": "whenever",
      "cameras": [
        {
          "bodies": null,
          "cameraSupports": null,
          "flash": null,
          "lenses": null,
          "monitors": null,
          "timecode": null
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

####################################################

Why am I receiving null values for the cameras subdocs?

Comment: Your typeDefs is missing the `Quote` type (not the source of the problem but could be useful in answering the question)

Comment: Also note that graphql types should be defined as *singular* - ex: `Camera` instead of `Cameras` - you want many cameras then you have `[Camera]` - your model is going to give you challenges later.

Comment: Added the correct typedefs.

Comment: Added the quote model.

Answer (score 0):

ok, your `Cameras` type is:

```
type Cameras {
    _id: ID
    bodies: [Bodies]
    lenses: [Item]
    flash: [Item]
    monitors: [Item]
    timecode: [Item]
    cameraSupports: [Item]
  }
```

But when your mutation inserts a quote object, the `cameras` input is:

```
"cameras":{
    "bodies":{
      "name":"r5c",
      "manufacturer": "Canon"
    },
    "cameraSupports":{
      "name":"5DmkIII",
      "manufacturer":"Canon"
      },
    "flash":{
      "name":"C100mkII",
      "manufacturer":"Canon"
      },
    "lenses":{
      "name":"D200",
      "manufacturer":"Nikon"
      },
    "monitors":{
      "name":"PD150",
      "manufacturer":"Sony"
      },
    "timecode":{
      "name":"trv17",
      "manufacturer":"Sony"
      }
  }
```

As you can see, `bodies` is a **single** `Bodies` object, not `[Bodies]`. Same for `lenses`, `flash` etc…

When you return your newly inserted quote from the mutation, GraphQL attempts to map the quote object to the type being requested. Wherever your document contains a single object and GraphQL is looking for an array it's going to return `undefined`.

This is a good case for where you really want to define types as one of a thing and not many of a thing. Your case is even worse because you're using `[Cameras]` in places which is essentially `[[Camera]]`. That makes it hard to keep track of the cardinality of the relationships.